# Full Page Video HTML5

Tags: css, html, video

hello all i found some article that you can make a full page background Video ..
the idea is :

**CSS:**

```
#bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}
#bg video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="bg"><video src="video/video.mp4"
 id="bg-video" muted autoplay loop ></video></div>
```

i want make 2 sections , the first section include the video with 500px height only  and the second include my content. but  when i tried to change #bg `position: fixed;` the Video become small and the content become under the video 
i make example on my host [My Example](http://mohammadsamy.com/Goejaza/) ,

Comment: You should probably consider compressing your video.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you want to have the `ContentWrapper` on your video? If so, try to nest this `div` into your `vediowrapper`. As I can see, the `vediowrapper` is closed before the `ContentWrapper` and therefore the `position:relative` has no effect on it since it is not contained.

Comment: @danJuwe look i want 2 section , video wrapper with 500px height and content wrapper to put my other divs after the video